# groupBy on multiple columns using my innerClass

Tags: c#, linq

I try to group by StringId and then by Name

```
var a = myList
                .GroupBy(item => new TcGroupByKey() 
{StringId = item.Id, ChannelName = item.ChannelName}).ToList();
```

I have created this inner class `TcGroupByKey`

so I can pass the result to `TrackingChannelRow` ctor

and will get strongly type argument and not `object`

```
 public TrackingChannelRow(ManageTcModel.TcGroupByKey tcGroupByKey,
            IGrouping<ManageTcModel.TcGroupByKey, TrackingChannelItem> subChannels,
            IEnumerable<Manager.TrackingChannels.Model.ToolbarItem> toolbars,
        IEnumerable<Manager.TrackingChannels.Model.BundleItem> bundles)
        {
```

But the group by doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We've no idea what error you're getting... a short but *complete* example would be really helpful. Note that GroupBy will only work if your type overrides Equals and GetHashCode appropriately. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Your query returns a list of group objects, with `TcGroupByKey` objects serving as keys. Is that not what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is to group by composite key...

Something similar to what Marc described in this post [Linq to SQL with Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210695/417747)

The key is to use 'anonymous' types - not the named one like you did - that LINQ can translate into SQL, otherwise there's an issue and that code can only run 'post SQL' (so you enumerate first then group but lose on the SQL integration, performance).

So, in your case it'd be something like this...

```
new {StringId = item.Id, ChannelName = item.ChannelName}
```

...instead of `new TcGroupByKey() {StringId = item.Id, ChannelName = item.ChannelName}`

There is similar problem with doing a 'Select' into anonymous (works) or named type (doesn't - unless, as I mentioned above, you separate the SQL and C#-only expressions part, a bit simplified).

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are asking linq to group your list by an object he doesn't recognize.

What's wrong with:

```
var a = myList.GroupBy(Id).GroupBy(ChannelName).ToList();
```